# Updating Vs New Question

Tags: discussion, support, meta

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Is my proof flawed or unclear?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463360/is-my-proof-flawed-or-unclear)

Someone answered my question and I was still hoping to get help about what my updated proof looks like - based on the advice given. Should I make a new thread with my updated proof, or should I modify it, or is there another option all together I should consider?

This may be considered a duplicate, the closest possible answer seems to be the first comment of [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9965/editing-the-question-vs-asking-a-new-question) 'duplicate.' If it is agreed that is the case, I apologize and will delete this question.

Comment: It seems like that first comment is the correct response to this.